# How do I use data validation lists in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a sheet in which the cell values are filled with a data validation list. Is it possible to bring this data validation to pivot table. Please help me on this issue to fix.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to test this, but this might be what you are looking for:

Create a dynamic named range using a formula similar to the following:

```
=OFFSET(mysheet!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(mysheet!$A:$A),10)
```

Then, for the input range of your dropdowns, refer to this range by its name.

([Source](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/73119-data-validation-list-pivot-table.html))